# C::* as a parameter for a template type C -- what is this syntax?

Tags: c++, syntax, function-pointers, sfinae

Consider this line:

```
template <typename C> static yes& test(reallyHas<std::string (C::*)(), &C::serialize>*) { }
```

I found it [here](https://jguegant.github.io/blogs/tech/sfinae-introduction.html), in an article on SFINAE. I struggle to understand that line. The comment above the line says "`std::string (C::*)()` is function pointer declaration."

I know function pointers as parameters to look like this:

`void foo(bar (fptr*)(cat c, meow m)){}`

But what is `::` doing there? `C` is a type and located at the same syntactic position as `fptr`. But `fptr` is the name of an entity (the pointer to the function passed as an argument), so... how do these to correspond exactly?

Comment: Look up "pointer to non-static class member function".  Those types of functions do not exist in `C`.

Comment: What do you mean these don't exist in `C`? I looked it up but I still don't understand what is going on here. Is `::*` an atomic expression? Or is it `::` and `*` composed? And if so, why `*`?

Comment: This code is meaningless in C; it's only valid in C++. `std::string (C::*)()` is a member function of class `C` that takes no arguments and returns a `std::string`

Comment: so `::*` IS an atomic expression then, yes?

Comment: @lotolmencre: `::*` is actually two tokens in sequence (`::` then `*`), unlike `.*` or `->*` when you use the pointer, which are single tokens.

Comment: @lotolmencre `C` has no such thing as non-static member functions as there are no such things as classes in `C` in the same way as C++ (you can emulate classes, but it is not built into the syntax of `C`).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: But pointer-to-member declarations also exist for data members, and C does have non-static data members.

Comment: @lotolmencre -- [Try to create a function pointer](http://ideone.com/KdZP9l).  You will see that there is no way to do that without using the syntax that is confusing you.

Comment: Compare: bare function pointer (`void (*fp)(int arg)`) vs member function pointer (`void (T::*mfp)(int arg)`).  Note that you had the `*` and identifier switched in your final code example.  And the identifier can be left out if it wouldn't be mentioned again, for example in a forward declaration.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie You seem to be mixing up the classname `C` with the programming language C .  OP never mentioned the latter

Comment: @BenVoigt IMHO your last comment is the valid answer that explains it all.